# Broken Documentation change suggestion

Tags: bug, documentation

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/12918) suggested change cannot be accepted or rejected ("An error has occurred during submission...") and has no change highlights. I am not sure what is broken, but it seems that something is...

Comment: And here is [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/8880) - same symptom (no changes highlighted) same problem (cannot be rejected). Possibly the original change was superseded by a later accepted one, but we should still be able to reject it because of this.

Comment: Or it should be automatically rejected

Comment: Here's [one more example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/8860) (also showing no changes) which cannot be rejected.